# Why is my python path pointing to a non existent file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I deleted every instance of python, versions, off my computer then re-installed it and when I type
`python -V` in cmd, it says `No Python at C:\(insert file path that does not exist)`. I went to my environment variables and added a new location in `Path` and it still shows the No python message. How do I fix this so I can use my new
`C:\(new destination)` for python?

Comment: Try ```python3```? I'm not sure if python 2 gets installed next to it automatically

Comment: @MichaelBianconi i get `'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: @AMC no I am not, I was doing this all on my pc

Comment: @GlenvillePecor Are they mutually exclusive or incompatible? In any case, I would really recommend it.

Comment: @AMC which one do you recommend?

Comment: _which one do you recommend?_ Which what?

Comment: `mutually exclusive or incompatible` @AMC

Comment: @GlenvillePecor I recommend using virtual environments, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @AMC I found the answer (shown below in answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that happened was that pycharms would not change the outdated path even tho I deleted / re-installed it countless times. I un-checked the `add to path` option and it worked